# Logical Error at Conditional Probability Question

Tags: probability

I am having a rather tough time wrapping my head around any possible logical fallacy in my solution to the following question as my answer is wrong:

1 percent of children have autism. A test for autism is developed such that 90% of autistic children are correctly identified as having autism but 3% of non-autistic children are mistakenly identified for having autism. A child is tested at 2 independent clinics. What is the probability that **both clinics give the same diagnosis?**

My solution:
Find the probabilities of any individual being tested positive and being tested negative. Then, square them and add them together (two clinics).

P(positive test) = (Has autism)(tested positive given has autism) + (Does not have autism)(tested positive given does not have autism)

Which would be: (0.01 * 0.9) + (0.99 * 0.03) = 0.0387

Similarly, the test for negative would be calculated to be 0.9613. Hence, my answer would be (0.0387)^2 + (0.9613)^2 = 0.9255

However, this is not the same answer as the solution. The solution suggests to do it in the way of P(Positive in one clinic & Positive in another clinic | Autistic) * P(A) + P(Negative in one clinic & Negative in the other clinic | Not autistic) * P(not Autistic) which would yield 0.94.

I don't quite understand why this is different from my solution though. Just where exactly am I making a logical error?

EDIT: Revised; thanks Michael Hardy for correcting me.

Comment: You are asking the probability of both clinics give the same diagnostics (no matter right or wrong) OR the probability of both clinics give the same CORRECT diagnostics??  Because, the suggestion in the solution is adequate to find the probability of both clinics give the same CORRECT diagnostics.

Comment: The probability of a child being autist and being indetified as such in both clinics is $(0.9)^2(0.01)$ . It is NOT  $[(0.9)(0.01)]^2$.

Comment: @RamiroGuerreiro Oh my goodness, big thanks to you and Michael Hardy! I get it now. I've been carelessly overlooking the fact that I treated the child to be autistic and/or not autistic twice at both clinics instead of once. I'll always bear this in mind now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1 percent of children have autism. A test for autism is developed such that 90% of autistic children are correctly identified as having autism but 3% of non-autistic children are mistakenly identified for having autism. A child is tested at 2 independent clinics. What is the probability that both clinics give the same diagnosis?

Step 1: Identify what is given.

- Let $A$ be the event that the child has autism.  $\mathsf P(A) = 0.01$
- Let $T_1, T_2$ be the events that the tests are positive at the two clinics, respectively.  $\mathsf P(T_n\mid A) = 0.90, \mathsf P(T_n\mid \neg A)=0.03$

Step 2: Identify what is asked.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(T_1=T_2)
 & = \mathsf P(T_1 = T_2\mid A)\mathsf P(A) + \mathsf P(T_1=T_2\mid A^\complement)\mathsf P(A^\complement)
\\[1ex] & = {\big(\mathsf P(T_1\mid A)\mathsf P(T_2\mid A)+\mathsf P(T_1^\complement\mid A)\mathsf P(T_2^\complement\mid A)\big)\mathsf P(A) + \ldots\\ \dots  \big(\mathsf P(T_1\mid A^\complement)\mathsf P(T_2\mid A^\complement)+\mathsf P(T_1^\complement\mid A^\complement)\mathsf P(T_2^\complement\mid A^\complement)\big)\mathsf P(A^\complement)}
\end{align}$$

Step 3: Substitute and evaluate.

---

Why is this different from your answer?  You've assumed that when the child goes to either clinic it *may or may not* have autism -- each time.  However, this neglects that it is the *same child*; it either has or does not have autism, but whichever it is, this *doesn't change* when it visits another clinic.

Hence you don't square the probability of being autistic.  $\mathsf P(A_1\cap A_2)=\mathsf P(A_1) \neq \mathsf P(A_1)\mathsf P(A_2)$

---

**Remark:**   Of course there's an error in the assumption of independence.   It works for the general population, but not for the same individual.   Because a child's histology does not change, the probability that two *of the same* tests on the *same* individual give the same result will be higher than assumption of independence suggests.   Hence why doctors don't subject patients to the *exact same* test multiple times to reduce false positive rates is because: it does not work.

Comment: Great answer! I felt that this answer addresses the question more directly and perfectly, although both answers are amazing and have been incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The second approach suggested ought to say this:
\begin{align}
& \Pr(\text{positive in one clinic & positive in another clinic} \mid \text{autistic})\cdot\Pr(\text{autistic}) \\
{} + {} & \Pr( \text{negative in one clinic & negative in the other clinic} \mid \text{autistic}) \cdot \Pr(\text{autistic}) \\
{} + {} & \Pr(\text{positive in one clinic & positive in the other clinic} \mid \text{not autistic}) \cdot \Pr(\text{not autistic}) \\
{} + {} & \Pr(\text{negative in one clinic & negative in the other clinic} \mid \text{not autistic}) \cdot \Pr(\text{not autistic})
\end{align}

Another problem: Your approach treats the two clinics' outcomes as independent.  They're not.  They are **conditionally** independent given the autism status. What is the conditional probability of a positive result at one clinic given a positive result at the other?  It is *more* than the unconditional probability of a positive test, because, given a positive test at one clinic, the probability of autism is then more than $0.01$.
$$
\Pr(\text{autism}\mid + ) = \frac{\Pr(\text{autism}) \cdot \Pr(+ \mid \text{autism})}{\Pr(+ )} = \frac{0.009}{0.009 + 0.0297 } \approx 0.232558.
$$

**Another issue** is this: We're testing the SAME person both times. That also interferes further with independence. For example, it is consistent with all of the information given in the statement of the problem that every patient either always tests positive at every clinic or always tests negative at every clinic. So even conditional independence is a stretch.

Comment: Just to clarify: In your second comment, are you arguing that the way the approach was written was imprecise, because the two outcomes are only conditionally independent, but the answer still came out correct because to find the probabilities (e.g., Pr(+ in clinic 1 and - in clinic 2|autism)), they are conditioning on "autism", hence the events can be treated as independent?

Comment: No --- you'll get a different answer if you do the first approach correctly.  Find the probability of autism given a positive test.  It's about $0.23$.  Then multiply that by the probability of a (second) positive test given autism.  That gives you the probability of two positive tests, given a random person about whom you don't know the autism status.

Comment: There's another issue that hasn't been mentioned: We're testing the SAME person both times.  That also interferes further with independence.  For example, it is consistent with all of the information given in the statement of the problem that every patient either always tests positive at every clinic or always tests negative at every clinic.  So even conditional independence is a stretch. ${}\qquad{}$